# Consulta en MySQL que tarda mucho en cargar en el index de la página

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin, trigger

Tengo una consulta realizada en **MySQL** la cual se encarga de traer los 10 términos más buscados en el sitio (el famoso Top 10). El problema es que esto se ejecuta en el index de mi sitio y la tabla (*estadistica*) de donde trae los datos siempre está creciendo en cantidad de registros (casi un millón). **Por ende tarda muchos segundos en cargar**. O sea cada vez que un usuario entra el sitio se ejecuta dicha consulta.
La consulta es la siguiente:

```
select Termino, count(distinct UserIp) as cant from estadistica 
where Encontrado=1 Group by Termino order by cant desc Limit 10
```

y luego en *PHP* lo muestro poniendo un contador, quedando algo así:

1. Clave candidata
2. Modelo orientado a objetos
3. Control por retroalimentación
4. Diccionario especializado
5. Bus de control
6. Quiet boot
7. Diccionario de datos
8. Instancia
9. Carpeta
10. Flash BIOS

Asismismo intente hacer una vista de esta consulta, pero en definitiva al llamar a la misma, el retardo va a ser igual. Al menos eso creo, es que la vista es la misma consulta realizada.

A lo mejor debería de hacer un **Trigger** o **Evento** para el cual sólo se ejecute (haga la consulta select) a una determinada hora cada día. Con esto, los datos mostrados siempre serían los mismo por 24 horas (algo fijo) y sólo los cambiaría cuando se genere ese Trigger o Evento (no sabría cual debería usar para el caso).

También podría generar esa consulta por fuera del index (para no cargar la página principal), pero los datos debo mostrarlo igual en el index.

En definitiva, ¿debería hacer un **Trigger** o **Evento** y que ejecute la consulta sólo una vez por día?, pero ese Top 10 siempre tiene que estar visible, sino me queda vacío en la página.

De ser así, ¿cómo podría confeccionar ese **Trigger** o **Evento** con la consulta que ya tengo?

La tabla creada es así:

```
CREATE TABLE `estadistica` (`UserIP` varchar(50) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,  
`suIngreso` longtext COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci,  
`Termino` varchar(50) CHARACTER SET utf8 DEFAULT NULL,  
`Fecha` datetime DEFAULT NULL,  
`Categoria` varchar(50) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
`Encontrado` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,  KEY `Fecha` (`Fecha`) )
 ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci
```

[image: Estructura de la tabla estadistica]

Al ejecutar `EXPLAIN` me genera lo de la imagen:
[image: Consulta con EXPLAIN]

Comment: Cómo está construida la tabla (el CREATE)? qué indices tiene?

Comment: ¿Tienen `INDEX` tus tablas?

Comment: Añade al principio de tu consulta (antes de SELECT) la palabra `EXPLAIN` separada por un espacio; ejecútala y agrega el resultado a tu pregunta.

Comment: Pon lo que has puesto como comentario como edición a tu pregunta. Como notarás, el código es ilegible en los comentarios.

Comment: me duele que digas que una consulta tarda, y no tengas un solo indice... por eso tarda.. hay que calcular todo cada vez que alguien entra.. supongo que ni siquiera la estas cacheando no? la estrategia aca, no va a ir como respuesta, pero son muchas cosas para hacer.. como primer paso, INDICES....

Comment: @gbianchi Que no duela, porque acá en PHPMyAdmin al ir a la estructura de la tabla me figura una llave (de color gris) en el campo 'Fecha' que dice que es índice al pasar el cursor por el mismo. Salvo que eso este equivocado.

Comment: Otra posibilidad es que hagas una tabla de tops. Y un trigger que al añadir un registro en la consulta estadísticas compruebe si debe sustituir a algun registro de la tops. Así solo tienes que consultar una tabla de 10registros. La primera vez te costará generarla, pero luego metes los registros del top en esa tabla y te irá más rápido

Comment: Claro.. pero tu consulta, no va por fecha, con lo cual, no lo va a usar.. para que lo va a usar, si igual tiene que recorrer todas las filas, para chequear si esta encontrado o no... y luego tiene que sumar todas las filas que encuentra.. con lo cual, tiene que sumar todo. Tu mejor opcion, es hacer una tarea programada todas las noches, o cada X horas, que calcule esto y deje los 10 registros en una tabla....

Comment: @gbianchi ¿O sea el index debería ser sobre el campo 'Termino'? (cosa que ya hice). Con respecto a la tarea programada, dices de hacer un **Trigger** (disparador) ¿y eso como lo podría realizar o donde hay un ejemplo que sirva para mi caso?

Comment: no. por lo menos, yo te dije una tarea programada. un trigger es un evento que se ejecuta cada vez que se realiza algo en una tabla. Una tarea programada, es algo que ejecuta la base de datos cada X cantidad de tiempo, o en determinado momento. Misma sintaxis, diferentes momentos de ejecucion...

Comment: y no.. que tiene que ver el campo termino? los indices se usan para resolver las partes del where, no del select.. fijate si el explain plan no dice que haces un full scan (o all table, o algo asi)...

Comment: Prueba con éste índice: `ALTER TABLE estadistica ADD INDEX enc_ter_usu( Encontrado, Termino, UserIp );`

Answer (score 0):

Después de realizar lo siguiente:

```
ALTER TABLE estadistica ADD INDEX enc_ter_usu(Encontrado, Termino, UserIp);
```

la consulta se redujo a menos segundos. Ahora al realizar el `EXPLAIN` quedo así:
[image: Consulta con EXPLAIN]